# JPA createQuery/TypedQuery, not recognising my table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

This is the function I am calling:

```
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        TypedQuery<Student> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Student as e", Student.class);
        List<Student> students = query.getResultList();

        return students;
    }
```

This is my Student class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Students")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String studentNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean uploaded;
    private boolean downloaded;
    private boolean active;

    // Default constructor
    public Student() {

    }
}
```

Problem solved! Thanks for help guys, still a new guy to this and made a few dumb mistakes!

Comment: the error (`SELECT e Students as e`) and code (`SELECT e FROM Student as e`) are inconsistent. Rewrite your post with what you are actually doing

Comment: @DN1 updated, didn't change the issue tho

Comment: Updated what?! You say you are executing `SELECT e FROM Student as e`, yet you are actually executing `SELECT e Student as e` (which is illegal syntax for the reasons the error message says). You also say you are using Hibernate (the tags) yet the error message is OpenJPA!!! And as for why you are "learning [JPA] off of google/stackoverflow" when there are many tutorials and docs out there ...

Comment: It started out as learning from google/stackoverflow now using a friends, uni book. The title is JPA/Hibernate so I assumed I was using Hibernate. No need to be so blunt, Thanks for the reply the problem has allready been solved @DN1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the issue.

The code itself is correct, Intellij however used the wrong standard JPA Framework configuration. After implementing the correct one, all the errors went away.

Another thing I changed was add this line to my persistence.xml, to make sure preload was true:

```
<property name="openjpa.MetaDataRepository" value="Preload=true" />
```

Thanks for all the people responding to this question!

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this:
"SELECT e FROM Student e"

Note that the entity is singular (Not students), you need to ad "FROM", and you dont't need to include the word "AS".

I learned JPA from this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm#BNBPY

You can view JPQL examples here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage002.htm#BNBRG

Comment: Well I specify in my Student class that the table name is Students so it doens't make any sense that my query would search in Student..

@Table(name = "Students")
public class Student {

Comment: JPQL is not SQL. JPQL mapping classes to the tables and in JPQL query you refer to the class name not the table name.

Comment: @AdamLesiak I get the same error if I change Students to Student

Comment: have you deleted word 'as' from query?

Comment: The as is not wrong, it is just not needed but can be used to clarify code. (found this in a course on JPA a friend gave to me)